# Ubuntu 22.04 - not detecting monitor aftwr suspend

Tags: usb, keyboard, 22.04

I am stuck -
The desktop is not detecting usb keyboard or mouse.
Also display is also not detected.

Hence unable to go to bios or reboot - but system is running

Comment: Sounds like some power management issue, that the hardware gets powered down upon suspend, but then on resume it isn't correctly powered up. First thing to try that comes to mind: test [the latest available kernel](https://askubuntu.com/a/142000/266507), see if that works. If it doesn't, try disabling power management of various devices and see if that fixes the problem. If I remember correctly, TLP seem to have offered a terminal user interface that allows to see current power management state of devices and change it. Start with disabling power management for all devices.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, My laptop uses a "Nvidia Geforce RTX 3070" VGA. I installed Nvidia driver "metapackage from nvidia-driver-525 (proprietary)" from additional drivers. It works fine.

Comment: I doubt that's related, given the OP said keyboard and mouse doesn't work as well. NVidia driver is unlikely to affect either of them. That said, there is a small chance that it may fix a problem with monitor *(e.g. if it is an unrelated one to the issue with keyboard and mouse)*. Either way, we don't know if OP even has an NVidia GPU.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and appreciate it. The issue I am facing is related to display driver. Currently I am having VGA, tried connecting to a LED also no change.  Since fasboot is enabled, unable to get into boot sequences or boot from a USB drive. I am taking to office where some support is available